# MLR3 vs. cv.glmnet tuning speed

Tags: r, glmnet, mlr3

I have a small dataset I am trying to train random forest and lasso models on. If I run cv.glmnet from *glmnet*, it performs k-fold CV and finds optimal lambda within 1 second. If I set up an AutoTuner from *MLR3* and train it in the same manner, it spends a long time computing. I have specified the search space and resolution for MLR3 to match that from cv.glmnet.

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = 5, alpha = 1, family="binomial", type.measure = "deviance", keep = FALSE)
end_time <- Sys.time()
      
end_time - start_time
```

Time difference of 0.8357668 secs

```
task = 
        TaskClassif$new(
          id = 'test', 
          backend = na.omit(test[, ..keep_all]), 
          target = 'tox'
        )

lrn_glmnet <- lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type="prob")
measure = msr("deviance")
resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
search_space = ps(s = p_dbl(lower = min(cv_model$lambda), upper = max(cv_model$lambda)))
terminator = trm("none")
tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution=100)

at = AutoTuner$new(lrn_glmnet, resampling, measure, terminator, tuner, search_space)

start_time <- Sys.time()      
at$train(task)
end_time <- Sys.time()

end_time - start_time
```

Time difference of 1.107895 mins

The difference here is approximately **80-fold**, in terms of computation time. I'd really like to use MLR3 since I'm doing nested CV and it's easy with that and I can benchmark learners together and not rely on the internal working of another package, but the two orders of magnitude are a very high price to pay (eg. for 100 iterations of 5 outer folds, I am looking at roughly 500 minutes vs. 500 seconds).

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions on improving speed here? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to tune the lambda parameter, the mlr3learners package also ships with the `classif.cv_glmnet` learner. The next version will include documentation to make this more visible.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do stratified nested k-fold CV if cv.glmnet is embedded within another resample() of MLR3? I can manually specify outer folds, but I would think that cv.glmnet is dynamically called for each one, making it difficult to manually specify the inner ones?

Comment: @Michael Connor when you use `cv.glmnet` with `mlr3` nested resampling then  you are actually using triple nested resampling. The inner most cv.glmnet would tune the lambda (regularization penalty), the middle loop would tune the alpha (autotuner that tunes ratio of lasso and ridge) and the outer loop would evaluate performance.

Comment: Thanks, I think I’m doing it right. If I wrap cv.glmnet with resample() then that is double or nested, correct? But how to specify inner fold IDs?